# IntelliJ's tomcat showing only 2 options

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

When I am updating my code or web files and trying to update tomcat server I am getting only 2 options, what settings I need to see all 4 options?
[image]

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have added Remote Tomcat configuration instead of the Local Tomcat. Please use the Local one to get more options.

Follow [this guide](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_a_simple_Web_application_for_Tomcat_in_IntelliJ_IDEA_12).